# Suppress update links warning and send password to excel via vba when opening a word document

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I want to suppress update links warning and send an open file password to excel via vba.    I have a word document that has linked tables to excel. The excel spreadsheets that contain the tables have links as well.  I'm able to open the word document and suppress all warnings and update the links in word with excel vba with no issues. Here's where it becomes tricky.  When word updates the links excel opens and requests the password to the excel file to open it.  Once password is entered excel issues the update links warning/option box.  I'm not sure how to the password from vba to excel and also pass the suppress update links warning to excel.  All over my vba code is in excel.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which file has the password? First Excel or the linked ones?

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1056155-help-disable-update-links-other-documents.html
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Word files ---linked to---- Excel files---- linked to ------Excel files.                      The word files and the first excel files contain links.

Comment: @macropod  -  I have read that website and many others.  I know how to disable link warning in excel and word using VBA.  I have done both.  This scenario is different because it involves links that are two file deep.  I have a work document that links to an excel file and the excel file links to a second excel file.  I can disable the warning in the word document using vba, but not the links in the first excel file when the opening the word document with VBA.

Comment: @macropod   -  I didn't post the question on mrexcel that you referenced.  Not sure who posted it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting:

```
wdApp.Options.UpdateLinksAtOpen = False
```

where 'wdApp' is the Word application, before you open the document, then programmatically updating the links.

Similarly, for Excel, you'd use:

```
xlApp.AskToUpdateLinks = False
```

where 'xlApp' is the Excel application.

Remember to re-set the options once you're done.

Comment: That works for the links in the word document, but doesn't seem to work for the links that are in the excel file.    See below.                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                       
 Word files ---linked to---- Excel files---- linked to ------Excel files. The word files and the first excel files contain links.

Comment: Excel code now supplied. Both of these are pretty basic settings that you could have found with each application's macro recorder.

Comment: I have tried the excel settings prior to posting this as well and it didn't work.  It only worked if I was using the VBA code to open the excel file directly, but not when I was used VBA to open the word document which has links to the excel file.  Please do not assume I didn't do my homework because I did.

Comment: Since you haven't posted any code, we have no way of knowing what you're doing. That said, you might try a different method of accessng the Excel data instead of using links. ADODB, for example, doesn't even require Excel to be started.

Comment: I have word documents that have to query data from excel.  Will ADODB help with that?  Looks like ADODB queries data from excel.

Comment: I wouldn't have suggested it if it couldn't be used that way. See, for example: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/35426-excel-word-data-import-based-userform-entry.html#post114827

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try copying my large excel tables from the excel worksheet into the word document.  My guess is there is a way to copy the tables to specific pages and positions on the page of an existing 100 page word document.